# How can I search for a specific word in an email thread in Gmail for Android?

Tags: gmail, email, search

I have opened an email thread (aka conversation) in Gmail  for Android. I would like to search a string (e.g., word or phrase).

How can I search for a specific word in an email thread in Gmail for Android?

Comment: the easiest and simplest workaround is to open the email thread in Chrome and search from there.  Not exactly an answer but is a workaround.

Comment: @William thank you, yes another workaround is print all as PDF.